# Converting nested attributes from string to numeric

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a GALLERY model containing nested SLIDE attributes. Some of my attributes are enum values. Without intervention my params hash receives the enum values as "0" or "1".  This results in an error e.g. '0' is not a valid gallery type.

Here is an example of my params hash:

> {"name"=>"Video quis terrax", "gallery_type"=>"0",
>   "slides_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"2", "order"=>"0",
>   "slide_type"=>"0", "image_cache"=>"", "embedded_url"=>"",
>   "_destroy"=>"0"},
>   "1441761800650"=>{"order"=>"0", "slide_type"=>"0",
>   "image"=>#,
>   @original_filename="large_veh_photo.jpg",
>   @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"gallery[slides_attributes][1441761800650][image]\";
>   filename=\"large_veh2.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">,
>   "image_cache"=>"", "embedded_url"=>"", "thumb_text"=>"2nd Image",
>   "_destroy"=>"0"}, 
>   "1441761824429"=>{"order"=>"0", "slide_type"=>"0",
>   "image_cache"=>"", "embedded_url"=>"", "_destroy"=>"0"}}}

You will notice that there are 3 slides in this example. The first one is identified by "0", the 2nd one by "1441761800650" and the 3rd one by "1441761824429". The first slide has already been saved. The 2nd one is a new slide and the 3rd one has no details filled in. These long number are automatically allocated by Rails in the view.

How can I change the "order" and "slide_type" attributes to numeric values before the controller attempts to do

```
@gallery.update(gallery_params)
```

Do I have any control over the random numbers assigned to my slides in the view?

Comment: Thank you Scott for putting me on the right path. I am providing the final solution here:  params['gallery']['slides_attributes'].each do |slide_attribute|
        params['gallery']['slides_attributes'][slide_attribute.first]['order'] = params['gallery']['slides_attributes'][slide_attribute.first]['order'].to_i
        params['gallery']['slides_attributes'][slide_attribute.first]['slide_type'] = params['gallery']['slides_attributes'][slide_attribute.first]['slide_type'].to_i
      end

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean up the params in the controller. You should be able to do something like this:

```
Class SomeController < ActionController
  before_filter: clean_gallery_params

  def clean_gallery_params
    params[:slides_attributes].each do |slide_attribute|
        params[:slides_attributes][slide_attribute][:order] = params[:slides_attributes][slide_attribute][:order].to_i
        params[:slides_attributes][slide_attribute][:slide_type] = params[:slides_attributes][slide_attribute][:slide_type].to_i
    end
  end

...
```